# How to convert MySQL Variables in JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to convert the following MySQL query to JPQL

```
SET @count:=0;
SELECT  (@count:=@count+1) AS serial_number, `web_address`
FROM company
```

I am getting the following exception.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'
```

Comment: JPQL does not know variables.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thanks for your reply. I just want JPQL query to return serial number, Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try with native query?

Comment: But your serial number is always 1! Do you need the number for insert into a table? If yes add an auto_increment column to that table column

Comment: @akuma8 Actually my original query is quite complicated and I managed to convert that to JPQL successfully with pagination and all the only thing remaining is a serial number, and also JPA pagination doesn't quite work well with the native query.